# Play a QuickTime video with JavaFX

Tags: java, video, javafx, media, quicktime

I try to open a MOV video file with JavaFX:

```
Media media = new Media ("file:/tmp/file.MOV");
```

But it throws a MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED.

However, if I simply change the file extension from .MOV to .MP4, it works perfectly, and the video is played with no error.

How can I force JavaFX to play my file without having to rename it?

Comment: Can you post more of your stack-trace? Edit: NVM found the cause. `Media` calls this method of `Locator` which throws that exception you're getting http://pastebin.com/NkTFT2Tk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that was a fun two hours. Here you go! Just make sure you have a zero byte mp4 file like in the example. It's pretty key in how it works.

```
public class TestFrame extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        File actualFile = new File("shelter.mov");
        File emptyfile = new File("blank.mp4");
        Media media = new Media(emptyfile.toURI().toString());
        copyData(media, actualFile);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
        try {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 720, 480);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void copyData(Media media, File f) {
        try {
            Field locatorField = media.getClass().getDeclaredField("jfxLocator");
            // Inside block credits:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection
            {
                Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
                modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
                modifiersField.setInt(locatorField, locatorField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
                locatorField.setAccessible(true);
            }
            CustomLocator customLocator = new CustomLocator(f.toURI());
            customLocator.init();
            customLocator.hack("video/mp4", 100000, f.toURI());
            locatorField.set(media, customLocator);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class CustomLocator extends Locator {
        public CustomLocator(URI uri) throws URISyntaxException {
            super(uri);
        }

        @Override
        public void init() {
            try {
                super.init();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        public void hack(String type, long length, URI uri){
            this.contentType = type;
            this.contentLength = length;
            this.uri = uri;
            this.cacheMedia();
        }
    }
}
```

How it works: Normally the default Locator throws an exception about the content type and it all ends there. Replacing the `Media`'s locator with a custom one then manually setting the contentType, length, and uri gets it to play without a peep.

Comment: This is a hack, but a clever hack!

Comment: As always, private fields and methods are subject to change from one version of Java to the next, so this may not work with future Java releases.

Comment: @VGR Yes, it would be better to fix the Java source code. I should maybe add a bug report.

Comment: @VGR It was the simplest solution I could find, but in reality MOV is mostly supported. It should just be added to the allowed MIME types. That or the classes should be extensible rather than being final.

Comment: Unfortunately I have an OutOfMemoryError on Windows VirtualBox: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
 at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source) at TestFrame$CustomLocator.hack
 at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.cacheMedia(Locator.java:285) at TestFrame$CustomLocator.hack

Comment: What kind of video are you playing? Also in this I used an arbitrary length that you may want to change, it may be the issue. I can test this after my exams today and edit the example accordingly.

Comment: The size of the video is 500Mb. I tried different length values but it didn't help.

Comment: Is it crashing in the middle of playback? Is it making it through a video or two before the crash occurs? I don't have any videos on-hand that aren't < 50MB to test with. You may just need to allocate more ram with JVM tags.